# Ajuda para mostrar dados do banco na tela

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, select, echo

estou fazendo um INNER JOIN entre duas tabelas do meu banco. Mas estou com dificuldade para mostrar o resultado organizado na tela, alguém poderia me ajudar?
As tabelas são de categoria e serviço (relacionado a categoria). Na tabela categoria tenho somente o id e o nome da categoria. Ja na tabela de serviço tenho várias informações, mas preciso trazer somente o código do serviço e o nome do serviço.
A query que montei foi esta:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM produto_tipo AS t1 INNER JOIN categorias AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.categoria
```

Onde PRODUTO_TIPO é a tabela de serviços e CATEGORIAS é a tabela de categoria, e o CAMPO categoria é a Chave Estrangeira (Sim, esta estranho, mas nao fui eu quem montou este BD). Quando executo esta query no phpmyadmin ele retorna as informações que preciso, mas, sem organização. Ele retorna assim:

```
id     cod     categoria    id   nome_categoria
118    ho         4         4      Hospedagem
117    dev        3         3      Desenvolvimento
116    444        3         3      Desenvolvimento
119    ho2        4         4      Hospedagem
120    emmkt      5         5      Marketing
121    rs         5         5      Marketing
```

Bem, primeiro vou dizer como quero as informações na tela...

```
Categoria: Hospedagem (Que tem id=4)
código       Serviço
  ho         Servidor
  ho2         SMTP


Categoria: Desenvolvimento(Que tem id=3)
código       Serviço
  ho         Servidor
  ho2         SMTP


Categoria: Marketing (Que tem id=5)
código       Serviço
 emmkt       E-mail Marketing
  rs         Rede social
```

Lembrando que as informações do campo SERVIÇO esta na tabela de serviços (PRODUTO_TIPO), com o campo chamado titulo.

No código PHP estou chamando essas informações assim:

```
<div class="row" align="center">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <h2>Categoria: <span style="color: #169F85;"><i><b>'. $row['nome_categoria'].'</b></i></span></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
    <h2>Ações: 
      <a href="categoria_form.php?n='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Editar"></i></a>
      <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Apagar(\''.$row['id'].'\');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Apagar"></i></a>
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center"><strong>'.$row['cod'].'</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center">'.$row['titulo'].'</td>
    <td class="text-center"><font class="btn btn-xs btn-success">R$ '.Decimal($row['valorCusto']).'</font></td>
    <td class="text-center"><font class="btn btn-xs btn-success">R$ '.Decimal($row['valorFinal']).'</font></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <a href="produtotipo_form.php?n='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Editar"></i></a>
      <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Apagar(\''.$row['id'].'\');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Apagar"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>';
```

E deste jeito ele aparece assim na tela:

```
Categoria: Hospedagem
Categoria: Desenvolvimento
Categoria: Desenvolvimento
Categoria: Hospedagem
Categoria: Marketing
Categoria: Marketing

código       Serviço
emmkt       E-mail Marketing
 rs         Rede social
 dev         Servidor
 444          SMTP
 ho          Servidor
 ho2          SMTP
```

Não sei como resolver isso :/

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Desde já, grato!

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o `ORDER BY` em sua consulta? Talvez usando um 
`ORDER BY nome_categoria ASC` e fazendo uns pequenos ajustes no seu PHP você consigo mostrar os dados da forma que deseja.

Algo assim no seu código PHP:

```
$categoria_atual = 0;
foreach($rows as $row) {
  if($categoria_atual != $row['id']) {
    $categoria_atual = $row['id'];
    echo '<tr><td colspan="5"><div class="row" align="center">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <h2>Categoria: <span style="color: #169F85;"><i><b>'. $row['nome_categoria'].'</b></i></span></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
              <h2>Ações: 
                <a href="categoria_form.php?n='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Editar"></i></a>
                <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Apagar(\''.$row['id'].'\');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Apagar"></i></a>
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div></td></tr>';
  }
  echo '<tr>
    <td class="text-center"><strong>'.$row['cod'].'</strong></td>
    <td class="text-center">'.$row['titulo'].'</td>
    <td class="text-center"><font class="btn btn-xs btn-success">R$ '.Decimal($row['valorCusto']).'</font></td>
    <td class="text-center"><font class="btn btn-xs btn-success">R$ '.Decimal($row['valorFinal']).'</font></td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <a href="produtotipo_form.php?n='.$row['id'].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Editar"></i></a>
      <a href="#" onClick="javascript:Apagar(\''.$row['id'].'\');" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-times" data-tip="tooltip" data-original-title="Apagar"></i></a>
    </td>
  </tr>';
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.